# Extraneous argument label 'localeID' in call (SwiftDate)

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am developing an iOs application with Swift and a total novice in application development. I use [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/UserGuide.md) external library to deal with dates. [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/UserGuide.md) is installed with CocoaPods and it is imported correctly in the project.

But I can't figure out why I get this error when I compile my project :

> Extraneous argument label 'localeID' in call

For this code :

```
let now = NSDate()

let nowHere = now.toString() // E.g. 21-Dec-15 12:00 CET
let nowInFrench = now.inRegion(localeID: "fr_FR").toString()
```

I understand that's because the parameters are not formatted correctly, but this an exemple from the [documentation](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/UserGuide.md#locale-conversions) so I am a little bit lost for this problem.

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oliver mentioned, the first problem is the argument label in

```
let nowInFrench = now.inRegion(localeID: "fr_FR").toString()
```

to fix your

> Extraneous argument label 'localeID' in call

error write it like this

```
let nowInFrench = now.inRegion("fr_FR").toString()
```

then you will come to the

> Cannot convert value of type string to expect argument type Region

Error. This means you cannot simply give the function `inRegion` a String object. It wants a Region objects. The [documentation](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/UserGuide.md) says use create a region

```
let paris = DateRegion(timeZoneID: "CEST", localeID: "fr_FR")
let nowInFrench = now.inRegion(paris).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being flagged up because for the first argument in a function the label doesn't need to be written, only the ones after that.

If you just write:

```
let nowInFrench = now.inRegion("fr_FR").toString()
```

The error should go away.

I don't know why the example is written that way, maybe just for clarity.

Edit: having looked at the documentation I do think they have just included the labels to be clear as to what type they are using as an argument.

Comment: I already tried this, this give me an other error :

_Cannot convert value of type string to expect argument type Region?_